# How would you implement proper https client authentication

Tags: java, android, authentication, https, backend

I have an android app that connects to my backend (apache2 server with some php scripts) via https to retrieve data stored in my database. My problem is, that I don't know how to properly authenticate my app to make sure my backend is not accessed by any other application.

I am currently using apache's basic authentication, meaning the script directory can only be accessed with a login and a password. As from what I know, android apps can easily be decompiled, which will reveal the credentials for the authentication as they're stored as plain text in the code. I could not think of a way which wouldn't get problematic if you consider someone decompiling your app.

What would be a propery way to authenticate the app though?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a token based authentication mechanism.

Calling an API exposed by an authentication service (OAuth2 alike), using some valid credentials provided at runtime by the user, will return an access token which will grant access to the desired resources.

The token will be then used as value for an Authorization Bearer header for the next API calls.

In this way, nothing is hard-coded, the token is generated dynamically.
You'll also have to take care of refreshing the access token after the expiration time.